# Automate proftpd-basic install on ubuntu using apt-get

Tags: automation, apt, automated-install, ubuntu-10.04, ftp

I'm trying to build a shell script to automate the installation of several packages onto an Ubuntu 10.04 server, and I'm having problems with proftpd-basic.

I'm using the command line

```
apt-get -qy install proftpd-basic >/tmp/install.log
```

For most packages, this approach would work fine, however proftpd-basic appears to require some interaction (it asks whether to perform an inetd or standalone installation).

Is it possible for me to pre-select this option on the command line somehow, as I don't want the user to be bothered by this question? - For info, if it matters, I want to choose the 'standalone' option.

**Edit:**

The interactive part of the process doesn't just require simple y/n answers, it requires that I use arrow keys to navigate to the option I want, requiring me to press enter to make the selection. This might have some bearing upon the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can "preseed" answers so that debconf sees you've answered the question already, and doesn't bother asking it again.

You need some tools from the `debconf-utils` package:

```
sudo apt-get install debconf-utils
```

Install your program and manually answer the questions once. Then, you can ask debconf what it stored in its database:

```
debconf-get-selections | grep proftpd-basic
```

That information can be input into `debconf-set-selections` (either by piping, or reading from a file).

Warner's answer is more cross-platform (debconf is a Debian-and-derivates only technology), but doesn't always work between versions, if the questions change; or in the case you have some debconf questions that are only asked if you have other packages installed.

Answer (score 3):

There's a variety of different solutions for things like this.  I prefer shell scripting, others might prefer other methods.

For interaction with things that require input and don't have flags to specify the answer, you can redirect input.  I would read the [apt-get manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) before taking this approach, as it may have native support for what you are trying to specify.  For example:

```
apt-get -qy install proftpd-basic <<**
RESPONSES GO HERE
**
```

You could also use something like [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).  Some clients do not always handle input redirection without additional effort.

For logging, you can use [tee](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tee.htm) and redirect STDERR and STDOUT when running the main script.  Example:

```
bash -x script.sh 2>&1 | tee script.log
```

I often like to run bash with `set -x` as well.  For build scripts, I prefer verbosity over cleaner output.

Comment: Thanks, +1 as I've learned two new useful shell scripting commands there, but (see the edit to my question), I'll have to accept crb's answer, as it works perfectly.

Comment: I appreciate the consideration!  =)  crb's answer definitely seems best suited for your situation.  I gave him a +1 myself.